# Javers JPA and DTO mapping

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa, dto, javers

I am new to Javers and so far I like it. I have played with Envers but think I like Javers better. In our application we are mapping Entities to DTOs at the service layer.

Javers have a method `findShadows(query)` which returns a `List<Shadow<Object>>` where Object is the entity. Since I do not expose entities for the client and only DTOs I wonder how I should go about so entities maps correctly to DTOs. At the same time I still need auditing data like user, date and id.

I first thought of just replacing the entities inside the `List<Shadow<DTO>>` but I have not found and easy way to do that. It also feels kinda fishy. Maybe I should create my own ShadowWrapper/extension thingy as a container for DTO or maybe there is another better way?